# Linear Algebra: Finding the matrix representation with respect to standard basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

I would appreciate some help with a linear algebra practice question, I'm studying for my final and I am stuck, this is a screenshot of the question:

[image: Screenshot of question]

Are my answers correct?

**a)**

$P_{2}$:

$
\begin{matrix}
  0 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0
 \end{matrix}$

$P_{1}$:

$
\begin{matrix}
  0 & 1 \\
  1 & 0
 \end{matrix}$

**b)**

Rank: 2 (as I have two pivots)

Nullity: 0 (as dim - rank= 2 - 2= 0)

Comment: No, the kernel of your map contains $1$. In general if $A:V\to W$ we have $\dim\ker A+\dim{\rm im} A=\dim V$. In your case $\dim V=3$, and $\dim{\rm im}\; A=2$.

Comment: Meaning your nullity cannot be 0.

Comment: You have to find one matrix $T$ so why do you write two matrices? The rank nullity theorem: $\dim P_2=3=\dim\ker T+\mathrm{rank}(T)=1+2$

Comment: a) The answer must be a $2\times 3$ matrix: you are going from $3$ dimensions to $2$ dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T_A$ be the matrix: 
$\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 0  
 \end{pmatrix}$

This matrix will remove the zero degree coefficient from any degree 2 or smaller polynomial (written as a vector), and will permute the other two coefficients.

As [Sami Ben Romdhane](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/63181/sami-ben-romdhane) indicates, your rank is 2 and your nullity is 1.

Comment: How did you know that the bottom row will no longer be there?

Comment: We are multiplying a vector with three entries by the matrix. We need to obtain a vector with two entries. The dimension of your codomain space is 2. So we cannot have three rows. We only want two rows so that our dimensions are correct.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!